# TSQL indexes on search fields, should I include Id

Tags: t-sql, database-indexes

Say I have a typical customer table;

```
Id Int Identity Primary Key, 
FirstName varchar(255), 
LastName varchar(255), 
Phone VarChar(30)
```

So primary key creates a clustered unique index on Id.

To make searching faster, I want to add indexes to the name fields.

My question is whether I should add the Id to those indexes or will those indexes tie themselves to the primary key anyway.

For instance;

```
Create Index IX_Customer_FirstLastName On Customers(FirstName, LastName, Id)
```

... is that overkill?

Is the following more or less efficient?

```
Create Index IX_Customer_FirstLastName On Customers(FirstName, LastName)
```

TIA

Comment: What would you be searching on? Always on full firstname/lastname or individually or...?

Comment: Well it's more of a generic question really. Does it provide any benefit to have the Primary Key field on any other index on a table?

Comment: Generally no, the answer from @MichaelFredrickson is pretty much covering it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wouldn't make sense to add the `ID` to your other index.  It would only be helpful if you had a large number of rows with identical `firstName` `lastName` combinations, and you already knew the `ID`...

But if you already knew the `ID` for the records that you're searching for, you could just search using your clustered index.

Additionally, every non-clustered index already contains a value for the clustered index so that it can look up the row using the clustered index after it has been found using the non-clustered index.  [You wouldn't have to include `ID` in your non-clustered index if you wanted to make it a covering index for the fields (`FirstName`, `LastName`, `Id`)](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/)

Final note, if you make a single index using `FirstName` and `LastName`, this index will only be used on searches that include the `FirstName`, the leading edge of your index.  If you plan on performing searches using just `LastName`, or just `FirstName`, create two indexes, one for each column.

Comment: Thanks Michael, the fact that non-clustered indexes point to the clustered index answers my question.

If I may, I'd just like to extend this question slightly.
If the Primary Key is a UniqueIdentifier, I would make it non-clustered for performance reasons. Would you still recommend leaving off the ID from the subsequent indexes then?

Comment: I still wouldn't make the `ID` part of the index, If you needed to [`INCLUDE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx) the ID in order to make the index covering, then that could be justifiable.. but I'm assuming that case is probably unlikely, and that you won't likely need to include the ID for that reason.  However, I would recommend against making your PK a unique identifier because [you'll still experience a lot of fragmentation even when using a non-clustered index with a GUID](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Clustered-or-nonclustered-index-on-a-random-GUID.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Michael, 
The choice of UniqueIdentifier on one project is out of my hands.
I did at least get the clustered indexes on them converted to non-clustered!